# How's RSP decreased here?

Tags: assembly, gdb

Through debug,I found that when `func` called in `main`,`RSP` is decreased by `8` from `0x7fffffffe960` to `0x7fffffffe958`:

```
(gdb) disas func
Dump of assembler code for function func:
0x0000000000400448 <func+0>:    push   %rbp
0x0000000000400449 <func+1>:    mov    %rsp,%rbp
0x000000000040044c <func+4>:    mov    $0x1,%eax
0x0000000000400451 <func+9>:    leaveq 
0x0000000000400452 <func+10>:   retq   
End of assembler dump.
(gdb) disas main
Dump of assembler code for function main:
0x0000000000400453 <main+0>:    push   %rbp
0x0000000000400454 <main+1>:    mov    %rsp,%rbp
0x0000000000400457 <main+4>:    callq  0x400448 <func>
0x000000000040045c <main+9>:    mov    $0x6,%eax
0x0000000000400461 <main+14>:   leaveq 
0x0000000000400462 <main+15>:   retq
```

Why `calla func` will make `rsp` decrease by `8`?

**UPDATE**

```
(gdb) x/4x 0x7fffffffe960
0x7fffffffe960: 0x00000000  0x00000000  0xf401d994  0x00000034
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because the return addresses are also 64 bits in size (eg. `0x0000000000400457`). When you call `func`, that value is placed onto the stack and the stack pointer decremented by that amount.

Comment: Why the return address `0x0000000000400457` is 8bytes,but register `rsp(0x7fffffffe960
)` only 6 bytes?

Comment: @compile-fan, it's not 6 bytes, it 8. It's only _displaying_ 6 but that will be a decisio the debugger makes. That return address would still be 8 bytes even if written as 0x400457 (without the leading zeros).

Comment: Actually it is 0x00007fffffffe960, which is eight bytes if you want to count. Some very clever people decided sometime ago that leading zeros may be omitted